# How to disable Spring Job Permanently

Tags: spring-batch

I'm using the Spring batch - version 1.1.X. Now I need to disable job permanently.

I don't want to comment the source code, is it possible to achieve it via some configuration?

Is there any crone expression which will never get executed?

```
job id="sapCertification" parent="simpleJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" incrementer="incrementer"
step id="sapCertificationStep" 
parent="skipLimitStep" next="sapbusinessstep" tasklet 
tasklet job
```